# Video player app

Tags: java, android, video, media-player

So I've got this line of code in my main activity. The ortogl.mp4 file is the root folder of my sd card and I've got a Sony Ericsson with Android 2.1.
The app installs and the console says error 1.0, while the phone displays the layout but not the video (it says unable to play the file).
Hints?

```
VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    v.setVideoPath(getString(R.string._sdcard_ortodgl_3gp));
    v.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    v.start();
    v.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I solved it

```
    File clip = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"ortodgl.mp4"); 

    VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    v.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());
    v.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    v.start();
    v.requestFocus();
```